# How to determine if a file has been copied to a target

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.6

When I add files to my Xcode project, I am asked if I want to "Copy items into destination groups's folders" and given a checkbox for each target I want the files added to.

First, how can I, after the fact of adding files (weeks or months later), determine if I copied the files into the destination?

Second, how can I, after the fact, determine which targets the files were added to?

Answer (score 0):

> First, how can I, after the fact of adding files (weeks or months
>   later), determine if I copied the files into the destination?

Find the files in your desired destination location. If It's available, then you have copied the files into the destination successfully:)

> Second, how can I, after the fact, determine which targets the files
>   were added to?

Select the file using Xcode and look at the Target Membership Section.

[image]